# R: Subset data table in a period of days according to several starting indices

Tags: r, date, data.table, subset, indices

Apology for improperly titling.

I have a data like:

```
DT <- data.table(date=as.Date(c("2013-07-02","2013-08-03","2013-09-04","2013-10-05","2013-11-06")), 
                 user =c(rep('A',5),rep('B',5),rep('C',5),rep('D',5),rep('E',5)), 
                 type =as.factor(letters[26:22]), val = runif(25))
```

and a subset of it, e.g., `dt = DT[c(2,8,12,18,21)]` derived from some conditions.

I want to further get another subset from `DT` according to `date` in `dt`.
E.g., use `date` in every row of `dt` as starting dates and 60 days after as ending dates, resulting in subset like this:

```
2: 2013-08-03    A    y 0.1049906
3: 2013-09-04    A    x 0.5823697
8: 2013-09-04    B    x 0.6254128
9: 2013-10-05    B    w 0.3616622
12: 2013-08-03    C    y 0.7924443
13: 2013-09-04    C    x 0.3651911
18: 2013-09-04    D    x 0.9989626
19: 2013-10-05    D    w 0.9782797
21: 2013-07-02    E    z 0.9337487
22: 2013-08-03    E    y 0.3784970
```

the desired output can be the one above or a list of users, each of which contains two rows in this example.

Comment: Does that mean you need other subsets not another subset?. For each date in dt you need to get a data frame from DT ??. Or am I missing something?

Comment: Yes, as I mentioned in the last sentence, an alternative desired output can be a list of data frames, whose first rows are those constituting `dt`. The desired output in the post is simply the concatenation of the list of data frames.

Answer (score 1):

This is pretty clear cut with the foverlaps function.

```
   library(data.table)

#create dummy end day for DT & real end day for dt
DT[,dateend := date]
dt[, dateend := date + 60]

#set the keys making sure dates are last 2
setkey(DT, user, date, dateend)
setkey(dt, user, date ,dateend)

#run foverlaps removing non matches then subsetting back to orig columns
subdt <- foverlaps(dt,DT, nomatch = 0)[,.(date, user, type, val)]

> subdt
          date user type       val
 1: 2013-08-03    A    y 0.9003246
 2: 2013-09-04    A    x 0.6521185
 3: 2013-09-04    B    x 0.9619138
 4: 2013-10-05    B    w 0.4214740
 5: 2013-08-03    C    y 0.1986591
 6: 2013-09-04    C    x 0.3056523
 7: 2013-09-04    D    x 0.7323238
 8: 2013-10-05    D    w 0.2416779
 9: 2013-08-02    E    z 0.4672380
10: 2013-08-03    E    y 0.6618275
11: 2013-09-04    E    x 0.5488879
```

Comment: I tried your code and `subdt` didn't look like the expected output showed by the OP

Comment: You are correct @Akrun, I had dt and DT reversed in the foverlaps funciton. I have edited and the output is now as expected by the OP

Comment: I tested the code using `DT <- data.table(date=as.Date(c("2013-08-02","2013-08-03","2013-09-04","2013-10-05","2013-11-06")), user =c(rep('A',5),rep('B',5),rep('C',5),rep('D',5),rep('E',5)), type =as.factor(letters[26:22]), val = runif(25))`, replacing the first date with `2013-08-02` and `subdt` incorrectly grabs it for user A, C and E who begins with `2013-08-03`, how can it be fixed?

Comment: @Fredom take a look at the edit. both the start and end date for DT are now the same. The foverlaps function actually deals quite well with 0 day period(in y), when using the 'any' parameter for match type(default). Since foverlaps is still 'under construction' you will want to specify that going forward if this code needs to still run in say a year. E begins on "2013-08-02" and is still picked up 3 times.